Laravel reverb websocket connection issue
Laravel reverb WebSocket is not connected.
I configured Reverb in the production server using the steps below.

Install reverb
I added the below code on the server but still getting

`location /app {
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8080;
}`

Still getting WebSocket connection failed.
Thanks in advance

would you mind to give the exact issue or detailed issue

same here .. were you able to solve the problem ?

Did you start reverb on your server on production? php artisan reverb:start. Can you curl request your reverb server?  curl -v https://example.com:8080 You need to add more information for your question.
